# is the limit as k approaches infinity of a Taylor Polynomial of order k, that approximates a function f, the same as the function itself?

Tags: calculus, analysis, approximation

Since Taylor polynomial approximation gets better as It's order gets bigger, so I was wondering, what happens when this order approaches infinity? Does the approximation equal the function itself and become perfect?

Thanks in advance. Loving calculus so far :)

Comment: If you take the limit as the order approaches infinity, the result becomes the Taylor series of the function (a type of power series). Under certain conditions on the function, the Taylor expansion represents the function exactly in certain subsets of its domain. For example, if you employ this limiting argument to the Taylor polynomials of $\exp$, $\sin$ or $\cos$ the resulting Taylor series will be equal to these functions on the whole real line.

Comment: Awesome, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no. Take, for instance,$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\Bbb R&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}e^{-1/x^2}&\text{ if }x\ne0\\0&\text{ if }x=0.\end{cases}\end{array}$$You can check that $(\forall n\in\Bbb Z_+):f^{(n)}(0)=0$. So, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n=0\ne f(x)$ (unless $x=0$).

Comment: Woah, that's awesome! I get It now

Answer (score 0):

There is a major difference between
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^p \frac {x^n}{n!}=\frac{ \Gamma (p+1,x)}{p!}e^x$$and
$$g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^n}{n!}=e^x$$ even if $p$ is very large.

Comment: I see. The original premise made a lot of sense on my head, but the arguments I have received already proved otherwise. Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The Taylor development will not converge to the function past singularities. For instance

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$$ will converge to $$\frac1{1-x}$$ only when $|x|<1$.

And as shown by José, the development might not converge at all to the function.

Comment: I see, thanks! :)